# Combination of values in pandas data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

This is my pandas dataframe:

```
       Item          Support_Count
0      BREAD              4
1      MILK               4
2      DIAPER             4
3      BEER               3
```

How will i generate all possible unique combinations of 2 and 3 set of items from the 1st column 'Item'.

Example(2 item sets):
(BREAD,MILK)
,(BREAD,DIAPER),(BREAD,BEER),(MILK,DIAPER) etc.

Example (3 item sets):
(BREAD,MILK,DIAPER),(BREAD,MILK,BEER),(MILK,DIAPER,BEER) etc.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the `itertools` library:

```
import itertools
list(itertools.combinations(df['Item'], 2))

[('BREAD', 'MILK'),
 ('BREAD', 'DIAPER'),
 ('BREAD', 'BEER'),
 ('MILK', 'DIAPER'),
 ('MILK', 'BEER'),
 ('DIAPER', 'BEER')]

list(itertools.combinations(df['Item'], 3))

[('BREAD', 'MILK', 'DIAPER'),
 ('BREAD', 'MILK', 'BEER'),
 ('BREAD', 'DIAPER', 'BEER'),
 ('MILK', 'DIAPER', 'BEER')]
```

Note: The number of combinations grows very quickly so generating all possible combinations may not be efficient. I recommend looking at [apriori algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apriori_algorithm) implementations if you haven't already done so.

Comment: Infact i am implementing the apriori algorithm only, can u please tel me a way to compare the combinations generated in the data set. Example to check the support count of (BREAD, MILK) in the data set how should i proceed.

Comment: Your dataframe should be a summary of a transactions table. Now that you calculated the support count for these items, based on your support threshold you need to calculate item pairs' counts. So you will call `itertools.combinations` on the items exceeding that threshold and count them. But again, you need the original transactions table for that.

Comment: ya, my doubt is how to calculate the support count for the combinations formed.

Comment: The answer for that question will be based on the structure of your original dataset. Do you have all items for a transaction in  one cell or are they in different rows with the same transaction id? etc. I'd recommend asking a new question with the input and desired output.