# compute symmetric function efficiently

Tags: python, pandas, python-itertools

I have two dataframes.
I need to apply a function to all possible couple of rows within the dataframe.

```
L=product(df.iterrows(),df.iterrows())

res=map(myfunc,L)
```

where myfunc(r1,r2)->float take two rows in input and returns one single value.
now,myfunc is symmetric thus

```
  myfunc(f1,f2)=myfunc(f2,f1)
```

for all possible input couples.

with product/map I compute the function twice the number of required times.
how to avoid elegantly these double computations?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36242735/combination-of-values-in-pandas-data-frame?

Comment: You can try a construct similar to [`DataFrame.corr()`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.25.1/pandas/core/frame.py#L7511-L7526). That's for all pairwise column combinations, but simple enough to think of it in terms of rows.

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35758612/most-efficient-way-to-construct-similarity-matrix) might be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `itertools.combinations` with the dataframe index:

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,(10,10)), index=[*'abcdefghij'], columns=[*'ABCDEFGHIJ'])

from itertools import combinations

def addTwoRows(r1, r2):
    return r1.sum() + r2.sum()

[(addTwoRows(df.loc[i], df.loc[j]),(i,j)) for i, j in combinations(df.index, 2)]
```

Output:

```
[(1166, ('a', 'b')),
 (1074, ('a', 'c')),
 (1035, ('a', 'd')),
 (922, ('a', 'e')),
 (849, ('a', 'f')),
 (920, ('a', 'g')),
 (968, ('a', 'h')),
 (1046, ('a', 'i')),
 (1043, ('a', 'j')),
 (1190, ('b', 'c')),
 (1151, ('b', 'd')),
 (1038, ('b', 'e')),
 (965, ('b', 'f')),
 (1036, ('b', 'g')),
 (1084, ('b', 'h')),
 (1162, ('b', 'i')),
 (1159, ('b', 'j')),
 (1059, ('c', 'd')),
 (946, ('c', 'e')),
 (873, ('c', 'f')),
 (944, ('c', 'g')),
 (992, ('c', 'h')),
 (1070, ('c', 'i')),
 (1067, ('c', 'j')),
 (907, ('d', 'e')),
 (834, ('d', 'f')),
 (905, ('d', 'g')),
 (953, ('d', 'h')),
 (1031, ('d', 'i')),
 (1028, ('d', 'j')),
 (721, ('e', 'f')),
 (792, ('e', 'g')),
 (840, ('e', 'h')),
 (918, ('e', 'i')),
 (915, ('e', 'j')),
 (719, ('f', 'g')),
 (767, ('f', 'h')),
 (845, ('f', 'i')),
 (842, ('f', 'j')),
 (838, ('g', 'h')),
 (916, ('g', 'i')),
 (913, ('g', 'j')),
 (964, ('h', 'i')),
 (961, ('h', 'j')),
 (1039, ('i', 'j'))]
```