# How to get common rows/columns between multiple files in all possible combinations - python/pandas

Tags: python, pandas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9mZN.png)I am beginner to programming, so forgive me if I'm not using right terms. I have data collected in multiple csv files. Now I want to collect data that contains common rows between two files (say File_1 and File_2). Likewise, I want data in all combinations (two files at a time)- File_1 & File_3, File_1 & File_N, File_2 & 3, File_2 & File_N and so on. I can use pd.merge if I want to do this between two files but to obtain data in different combinations I need a function. Can any help with a function in python/pandas to perform this task.

Example of what my data looks like:

[Here if I want to calculate common alphabets between multiple files, in all possible combinations][2]

Thank you so much in advance

Comment: MMore than a function, I'd say you need a loop.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". We appreciate that you might be new, but we do expect evidence of the effort you've put into this. Where did you search? Why didn't it help? If it did, where is the code you wrote to test what you learned? If you didn't write code, why not? If you did, what is the minimal code that demonstrates the problem you encountered, along with the explanation of the problem, and the minimal input data and the expected result? Without that it's hard to help you.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, nor is it a substitute for guides, tutorials, and documentation. See: [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors.

Answer (score -1):

1- Create a list of file name pairs using itertools.  (Not the only way you can do this, but let's try to make it more pythonic)

Here is a quick link to an example: 
[Combination of values in pandas data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36242735/combination-of-values-in-pandas-data-frame)

2- It is hard to conceive how you should ingest each file without knowing what kind of data you have.  But assuming that you have csv files, you can use pandas to read each file pair and join them on the field of your choice to each other and export the results.

I hope this gives you a rough idea how to do this.  I suggest posting some example data to 
get more specific solutions.

Comment: Thank you. I posted a link of an example data [click on 'enter image description here']. I have 116 csv files, so iterating a file pair at a time will take substantial amount time. If there is way to get all common rows that belonged to a particular column between these multiples files (two data files comparison at a time), that'd be great. But I am not able to figure how to write a loop for it.